# Between or within subjects?

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, experiment-design

So I have a 2x3 design with two categorical IVs, one is Country, the other is Message type (type A, type B, and control).
I've found published studies with very similar design that do both in between subjects or mixed (message type as within subjects variable) analysis. My question is, is a between subjects completely wrong? Do I need to analyze this as mixed design?